# missing some values from .CSV while writing into DataTable

Tags: c#

I am getting .csv file from outside, and writing in data table, using OLEDB.
it is working good but one value in a row not appearing in the table.

my code to  write into data table is

```
File1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Uploads\\" + StrFileName));
TextBox2.Text = StrFileName;
int i = 0;
string strCon;
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("Uploads\\") + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"";//
String abc = TextBox2.Text;
OleDbConnection olecon = new OleDbConnection(strCon);
OleDbDataAdapter myda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + abc + "]", strCon);
DataTable myds = new DataTable();
myda.Fill(myds);
```

My Problem is, after get the table from .CSV i am reading one by one row and inserting into 
my sql server table, but one of the row in middle having data in .CSV File but not appearing in the Data Table.

This is How i am getting data:

```
for (i = 0; i <= myds.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    String si21;
    String si11 = "0";
    if (myds.Rows[i][5].ToString().Length == 9)
    {
        si21 = si11 + myds.Rows[i][5].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        si21 = myds.Rows[i][5].ToString();
    }
}
```

only one Particular value in a row(Ex : 2507141012) having 10 digits is missing, but remaining 10 digits values of other rows are normally appearing.
 in sql table inserting like

```
109   0408143119         NULL   NULL    0     2.3   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    
110  --heres value miss--  NULL NULL    NULL    0   2.19    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
111 0408143117         NULL   NULL    NULL    0    2.29    NULL     NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Some one help me.

Comment: try LumenWorks csv reader http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader it might help you .

Comment: Set a conditional break point in the loop on `i == 109`. Take a look at the last column of row 109, there may be a missing line delimiter.

Comment: the missing value in the data table only.But it is appearing in .CSV file. After read and write in the data table i am doing loop. I assume the problem is in read the .CSV file.How can in get entire data from .CSV into DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same issue. While seeing data in database i found many of columns data got missed. You can use below approach to get rid from this issue.

```
string CSVFilePathName = @file.DirectoryName + "\\" + file.Name;
                        string[] Lines = File.ReadAllLines(CSVFilePathName);
                        string[] Fields;
                        Fields = Lines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });
                        int Cols = Fields.GetLength(0);
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        //1st row must be column names; force lower case to ensure matching later on.
                        for (int i = 0; i < Cols; i++)
                            dt.Columns.Add(Fields[i].ToLower(), typeof(string));
                        DataRow Row;
                        for (int i = 1; i < Lines.GetLength(0); i++)
                        {
                            Fields = Lines[i].Split(new char[] { ',' });
                            Row = dt.NewRow();
                            for (int f = 0; f < Cols; f++)
                                Row[f] = Fields[f];
                            dt.Rows.Add(Row);
                        }
```